# Kafka server fails to start with KAFKA SASL OAUTH

Tags: apache-kafka

I need help in setting up kafka with SASL below are the list of configurations.

It looks like producer is working fine and am missing something for zookeeper/kafka server configuration.

Can someone help me how to configure zookeeper and kafka server?

Appreciate your help in advance.

thanks.

- Producer Properties

  ```
  sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER,
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:8082,
  value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer,
  sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required signedLoginStringClaim_sub="testInstanceId" signedLoginKeyServiceClass="test.security.FileSystemKeyService" signedLoginKeyServiceProperties="baseDir=/tmp/kakfa/keys";,
  key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer,
  sasl.login.callback.handler.class=test.security.OAuthBearerSignedLoginCallbackHandler,
  security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
  ```
- Kafka config/server.properties

  ```
  listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT://:19092
  security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
  sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=OAUTHBEARER
  listener.name.sasl_plaintext.sasl.enabled.mechanisms=OAUTHBEARER
  listener.name.sasl_plaintext.oauthbearer.sasl.login.callback.handler.class=test.security.OAuthBearerSignedLoginCallbackHandler
  listener.name.sasl_plaintext.oauthbearer.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=test.security.OAuthBearerSignedValidatorCallbackHandler
  authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
  super.users=User:admin
  ```
- Jaas config - kafka_server_jaas.conf

  ```
  sasl_plaintext.KafkaServer {
     org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required
     signedLoginStringClaim_sub=admin
     signedLoginKeyServiceClass=test.security.FileSystemKeyService
     signedValidatorKeyServiceClass=test.security.FileSystemKeyService
     signedLoginKeyServiceProperties=baseDir=/scratch/kdevaiah/kakfa/keys;
  };
  ```

  ```
  export KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$base_dir/../config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
  ```
- Start zookeeper, comes up properly.
- Starting kafka server fails with below exception.

> Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
>   org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading
>   Zookeeper JAAS login context 'Client'
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled(JaasUtils.java:45)
>           at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:373)
>           at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:207)
>           at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
>           at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
>           at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
>           Line 6: expected [option key]
>           at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.(ConfigFile.java:137)
>           at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.(ConfigFile.java:102)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration

Comment: To make it easier to read, please consider using code formatting for the configuration that you've included